Write module Sympy codegen
I have a set of matrix and I would like to generate a code that compute the matrix, to plug it into another code already done. My problem is I don't know the variables that I need to compute theses matrices but I know all the possible variables. So I would like to create a module when called do something like this CALL eq2(mu,zeta,phi,out) and the matrix is stored in out and phi can be put as an input even it is not used. I tried with argument sequence but I can't find a way to deal with it.
def test():
   A=sy.Matrix.zeros(2,2)
   A[0,0]=2*mu
   A[0,1]=3*mu
   A[1,0]=2*phi
   A[1,1]=2*zeta
   B=sy.Matrix.zeros(2,2)
   B[0,0]=0
   B[0,1]=6*mu
   B[1,0]=0
   B[1,1]=5*zeta
   

   test=codegen([('eq1',A),('eq2',B)],'f95','test_routine_matrix',argument_sequence=(mu,phi,zeta,out),to_files=True)
   return()

test()

Thank you

Are you trying to make it a function that you can call in Python or a different language?

In a different language fortran 95 :)
